# Bibtex from Mendeley doesn't cite author and year

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib, mendeley

I am using Mendeley as a citation manager and I have produced a `.bib` from my bibliography.
I am using this as my `\bibiography`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[Conny]{fncychap} %lets me choose styles for the chapter section
\ChNameAsIs
\ChTitleAsIs
\ChTitleVar{\Huge} %size of letters

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{apalike}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\begin{document}
\title{Proposal for PhD project}
\author{xxx}
\maketitle
\newpage

\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

---document chapters and stuff

\bibliography{/Users/xxx/Documents/Latexdocs/Bibtex/library}
```

I get the error message

```
! Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations.

(natbib)                Press <return> to continue in numerical citation style.


See the natbib package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.8 ...mmand\NAT@force@numbers{}\NAT@force@numbers
```

when I cite, it comes in the standard number citation but I want to change it to author, year or only (year) when necessary.

I am trying with the `natbib` package and `apalike` style however, it doesn't work and keeps showing the numbers.

My guess is that the .bib is not consistent and this is causing an error for `natbib`.

Does anyone know how to use the Mendeley `.bib` for the document whilst still being able to change the citation from numbers to author and year?

(I am learning Latex thus the non-technical jargon)

Comment: In general `apalike` should be compatible with `natbib`'s `authoryear` option. So things should work. If you load `natbib` and get numbers, then you (or a package or class you load) must load `natbib` with the option `numbers` or pass that option on to it. Make sure that you load `natbib` with the option `authoryear`. For that option to work properly, your entries must have an author and a year, if an entry is missing that information you may get an error. We can offer more specific help if you can show us an example of what you are doing so far (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/).

Comment: \usepackage[Conny]{fncychap} %lets me choose styles for the chapter section
\ChNameAsIs
\ChTitleAsIs
\ChTitleVar{\Huge} %size of letters
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\begin{document}
 
 \title{Proposal for PhD project}
 \author{XXX}
 \maketitle
 \newpage
 
 \pagenumbering{roman}
 \tableofcontents
 \newpage
 \pagenumbering{arabic}

Comment: \bibliography{/Users/XXX/Documents/Latexdocs/Bibtex/library}

Comment: Hi, this is so far the code that I have, it is very simple but I have a question, how can I load natbib with the authoryear option?

Comment: Apart from not loading the `apalike` *package* which shouldn't matter, that looks right. `natbib` assumes authoryear unless told otherwise.

Comment: Please add the code to the question directly. Please also try to make the code compilable. From what I have seen so far this should work, but (1) I don't know if your `.bib` file contains weird stuff, (2) I don't know your document class and if it does weird stuff. It would help greatly if you could convert the code snippets into a fully working minimal example in the sense of https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864. It would also help if you could report any errors or warning messages you get.

Comment: You might also try a very minimal file: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}\usepackage{apalike}\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\begin{document}
This is a citation for a book: \citep{book-full}.
\bibliography{xampl}
\end{document}`

Comment: Hi, yes sorry about that. the code has been added. the .bib is generated automatically by mendeley

Comment: this is a warning Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations. ...mand\NAT@force@numbers{}\NAT@force@numbers\providecommand\NAT@force@numbers{}\NAT@force@numbers

Comment: Aha! Together with the code we have seen so far that error message suggests that there is indeed an issue with your `.bib` file. Can you try and narrow down which entry (or entries) might be responsible? Start from *really* small document like the one in Paul's comment above and add your citations one by one until you find the citation that throws the error.

Comment: Delete the instruction `\usepackage{apalike}`, change `\usepackage{natbib}` to `\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}`, delete all aux files, and perform a full recompile cycle (latex, bibtex, and latex twice more).

Comment: @PaulStanley - It's not a good idea to load both `natbib` and `apalike`. Choose one or the other (I would choose `natbib`...), but not both.

Comment: Woohoo it is fixed! so, I deleted the apalike package and left the code as: 
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}

Then i compiled latex then the bibliography and some warning came out directing me to the problem in the Mendeley library (so easy, it told me what was wrong) then i compiled twice more and it is done!

Thank you sooo much! everyone helped me quite  a lot

Comment: Do you want to write up a quick answer that explains what was wrong, so other people can benefit from it?

Comment: @moewe - I think the OP's "Woohoo it is fixed" jubilation came in reaction to the answer I posted... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Some comments and suggestions.

- Mendeley is *not* a citation manager. Instead, it's an external program that assembles bib files, usually from various online sources. Mendeley doesn't do anything related to creating or managing citation call-outs in a LaTeX document.
- It's not a good idea to load both the `apalike` and the `natbib` citation management packages. (Yes, these packages help you manage the creation of citation call-outs, and can thus be called citation manager packages.) Choose one or the other package, *but not both*.

  For what it's worth, I recommend employing the `natbib` package.
- If you employ the `natbib` package as well as the `apalike` bibliography style, it's advisable -- though not strictly necessary -- to load the package with the option `authoryear`. This is especially true if you're switching from some other bibliography style to `apalike`.

Be sure to perform a full recompile cycle (LaTeX-BibTeX-LaTeX-LaTeX) whenever you load a new citation management package or a new bibliography style.

Here's the output of a simplified form of your example code.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{library.bib}
@misc{aa:99,
   author  = "Anne Author",
   title   = "Thoughts",
   year    = 1999,
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\begin{document}
\cite{aa:99}
\bibliography{library}
\end{document}
```